# Dynamic 2D array in typedef

Tags: c, arrays

How do I get this to work? I am not sure how many invoices a customer will be assigned to and want to leave it dynamic. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _cust{
    int id;
    int invoices[][2];
} cust;

cust account[] = {
    {1,{10,100}},
    {2,{{10,100},{20,200}}},
    {3,{{10,100},{20,200},{30,300}}}
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", account[0].invoices[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", account[1].invoices[1][0]);
    printf("%d\n", account[2].invoices[2][0]);
    return 0;
    }
```

When I run this code I get following error ...

```
error: initialization of flexible array member in a nested context
```

If I give fill in a number something like this int invoices[3][2], the code runs fine.

Comment: That's not how zero-length arrays work. They can only be used with dynamic allocation (as the name "dynamic" suggests).

Answer (score 1):

You can change `invoices` to `int** invoices` and then allocate dynamically using `malloc()`.
You can allocate a 2D array like this:

```
int** theArray;
theArray = (int**) malloc(arraySizeX*sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < arraySizeX; i++)
   theArray[i] = (int*) malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: This is not an allocation of a 2D array, but of an emulation of such a thing. Also, don't cast the return of `malloc`, this is not C++.

Comment: What would be the real dynamic allocation of a 2D array then?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: You're doing the same thing except one dimension of the array is fixed to 2.

Comment: No, not at all. You are allocating an array of pointers and then a different chunk for each line. Real 2D arrays are allocated contiguously and there is no indirection. The element of a 2D array (something like `array[i][j]`) can be computed by arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to an array with two elements would look like this:

```
int (*array)[2];
```

but it would perhaps be easier for you to use a `typedef` first:

```
typedef int pair[2];
.
.
pair * array;
```

and you can allocate a large chunk to such a beast just in on go. If you have a C99 (or upwards) compatible compiler this would read like

```
array = malloc(sizeof(pair[n]));
```